# PHP POST and REQUEST are empty?

Tags: php, html, nginx, raspbian

I'm running a Raspberry Pi (`Model B` I think) with Raspbian. I followed the [**instructions**](http://www.raspipress.com/2014/06/tutorial-install-nginx-and-php-on-raspbian/) to install a web server (with a few tweaks as parts appeared outdated and I also installed telnet in order to send emails from PHP).

I have a form on the webpage and when I set it to use the `GET` method `var_dump($_GET)` returns an array of the inputs as expected however when I set it to use `POST` method `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` are empty (`var_dump` returns `array(0) {}`).

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="text/plain" id="contactForm">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact us:</legend>
        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="first name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="last name"><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="text" name="mail" value="e-mail address"><br>
        Phone number:<br>
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="phone number"><br>
         Reason for contacting:
        <select form="contactForm" name="reason">
            <option value="purchase">Purchase</option>
            <option value="complaint">Complaint</option>
            <option value="business">Business</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
       </select>
       Comment:<br>
       <textarea rows="12" cols="70" name="comment" form="contactF$
       <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP (It's as a `<?PHP ?>` at the end of the HTML file, I have check it runs using debug):

```
 var_dump($_POST);
 var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

my `/usr/share/doc/debian-reference-common/html/.htaccess` and
my `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` files can be found [**here**](http://pastebin.com/uc9ZJ3Fd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a `name` attribute to your submit button HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

and then do a check on that value in your PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // do stuff here
    echo $_POST['firstname'] . "<br>";
    echo $_POST['lastname'] . "<br>";
    echo $_POST['mail'] . "<br>";
    echo $_POST['phone'] . "<br>";
    echo $_POST['reason'] . "<br>";
    echo $_POST['comment'];
}
?>
```

You should also add a form action pointing to the page in which the above php is located, in this case, it is the same page:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="contactForm">
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it didn't work for me, the arrays are still empty

Comment: I copied your <form> line but not the rest, did you change something else we well as the form line?

Comment: okay, just copied it now and it works, what else did you change then, itll be interesting to know what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to include `<form action='page'></form>` for the submit to work. Unless you are AJAXing the input values.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that doesn't work either. Nor does action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"

Comment: since it is a post request, it will not redirect the page, so the php output wont show. if you want to capture a response from the server, use AJAX. @KEC